# What do different things mean in ftp dir output

Tags: python, ftp

So I am getting a list of everything in a directory on a ftp server using

```
data = []
ftp.dir(data.append)
```

then when I print this out I get back this list

```
drwxrwxrwx   2 0        0        16384 Oct  3 12:54 Andrew
drwxrwxrwx   2 0        0        16384 Oct  1 16:06 Other Files
drwxrwxrwx   2 0        0        16384 Oct  3 13:13 Python and FTP
-rwxr-xr-x   1 0        0        657 Oct  2 03:55 READ ME.txt
-rwxr-xr-x   1 0        0        235 Sep 30 05:16 START HERE.html
drwxrwxrwx   2 0        0        16384 Oct  3 13:18 Test Directory
drwxrwxrwx   2 0        0        16384 Oct  3 01:06 Test Website
drwxrwxrwx   7 0        0        16384 Oct  1 16:21 Website
-rwxr-xr-x   1 0        0        235 Sep 30 05:16 index.html
```

What I am wondering is what all the different things mean...

I figured out that `d` means directory and `-` means file, but what about the rest in the string `drwxrwxrwx` or `-rwxr-xr-x`, and then what do the other things mean? Like on the first line, I presume the `2` is the amount of files? but what about 0 and 0, then what are the other numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `drwxrwxrwx`, `d` means it is a directory, the first `rwx` (`r`=read, `w`=write, `x`=execute) in `rwxrwxrwx` is the permission for the owner/user, the second `rwx` is the permission for the group, and the third `rwx` is the permission for others.

```
2 0        0        16384 Oct  3 12:54 Andrew
```

The `2` here is the number of *immediate* subdirectories it has *plus* its parent directory and itself. So in this case it suggests directory `Andrew` has no subdirectories.

If however, it is for non-directory, `2` will stand for the number of hardlinks linked to it.

The `0  0` here is the UID and GID of the user.

The `16384` is the size. Note that, since `directory` in Unix is essentially a file too, this number therefore does not represent the total size of all files belongs to this directory, it simply refers to the size of this directory *file*.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the output you get from running `ls -l` on a Linux command line. A good reference can be found [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/07/linux-ls-command-examples/#more-550), but basically you're seeing permissions (after the `d`/`-`, you have the read/write/execute permissions for the owner/group/others), the number of links, the owner, the group, the size of the file, the date it was last modified and the filename. It looks like you have digits for your owner/group fields, so it is possible that this is listing something else (I'm not a command line expert by any means, so this is very possible :) ). The rest appears to match up.